# Append form partial in the new view of the same model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, view, model

i'd like to use the same model to create in one view (new.erb.html) more records at once with a single submit.

for example I've a model called Report with some fields such title, description and date

how can render same form partial many times when i click an add button? i think is not a nasted model's problem because is always the same model actions.
Thanks

Comment: hm, maybe I do not understend your question well, but ewhat exactly are you trying to do? Do you use js to append that forms?

Comment: yes i'd like to use jquery and i want to manage array for create controller action of the same model

Comment: so, you can just add as many forms as you need with JQuery's append, and they don't have to differ: just use Khustochka's hint 'bout model[][name] names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (I haven't test the code myself):

haml:

```
.model
  %input{:name => "model[][name]"}
  %input{:name => "model[][desc]"}
  %input{:name => "model[][date]"}
.container
%button.add-model
```

js:

```
$('.add-model').click(function(){
  $('.model').clone().first().appendTo('.container');
})
```

controller:

```
def save
   params[:model].each do |props|
     Model.create(props)
   end
end
```

Comment: ok thanks, i'm working on this solution, but i don't use haml, i use html with the support of SimpleForm gem, do you know how to change the  inputs name with the format model[][name]?

Comment: I'm not sure if SimpleForm has helpers to make the names like "model[][name]". Can you specify the name explicily? something like f.input :name, :name => "model[][name]"?

Comment: yes it works with :input_html => "model[][name]" there is not an helper, now the javascript works fine but the create action is not working, it save only the last inputs

Comment: here debug comes to action: look what exactly is in params[:model], how many elements? You have to ensure that the entire form data gets to the controller. You can use network console in your browser too.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is using JavaScript (jQuery) - on page load I save the only rendered form into JS variable (actually not the form, but the inputs inside it), and then on clicking "Add more" link append more inputs into the form.

And to save many objects at once you will need handcrafted input names (something like `model[][name]` in order to send an array of values), as well as controller that accepts array.