# Rails 4 how to create and listing in the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model product and I want to create and then list under the text_field

in my controller

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController
def buy
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @product.save
                format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully added.'}
            else
                format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Failed to added.'}
            end
        end
    end

    private

    def product_params
        params.permit(:name, :description)
    end
```

end

and view

```
<%= simple_form_for @product, :url => { :controller => 'product', :action => 'buy'} do |f| %>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= f.button :label => 'BUY', :class => 'btn add-product btn-primary' %>

<% end %>
```

and I try to list in the same view

```
        <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <%= product.name %>
        <%= product.description %>
```

and script

```
<script>
 $('.add-product').click(function(){
  $('.product').clone().first().appendTo('.container');
 })
```

I'm not sure the code can be run or not 
Cuz I got a problem with

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

in this   <%= simple_form_for @product, :url => { :controller => 'product', :action => 'buy'} do |f| %>

my question is like [Append form partial in the new view of the same model in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483722/append-form-partial-in-the-new-view-of-the-same-model-in-rails)
but I can't use   %input{:name => "model[][name]"} to be my input

Can help me how to fix my code
 thanks~

Answer (score 1):

`@pruduct` is a typo.  make it `@product`. does that fix it?

based on comments.

```
class ProductController < ApplicationController 

  def index
    @products = Product.all 
    @product = Produc.new
  end 

  def buy
    @product = Product.new(product_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to products_path, notice: 'Product was successfully added.'}
      else
        format.html  do
          @products = Product.all
          flash.now[:error] = 'Failed to add product'
          render action: 'index'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Had to change the redirect on failed since if it didn't save you won't have an ID, and won't be able to redirect to it.

Then in your `index.html.erb`  view

```
<%= simple_form_for @product, :url => { :controller => 'product', :action => 'buy'} do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.button :label => 'BUY', :class => 'btn add-product btn-primary' %>
<% end %>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <%= product.name %>
  <%= product.description %>
<% end %>
```

I think that should do what you are asking.

Comment: what is the view you have posted above? is it the new action? the index action?

Comment: basically you have a null value for `@product`,  so whatever action is rendering the view with that simple form call in it doesn't have `@product` set.

Comment: well, so I need to create a new product in the beginning?I'm not use the scaffold so it's a new action "buy".But how can I give a new product in the beginning.If I def new action and @product = Product.new. This will reture undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass the error

Comment: you can do `simple_form_for Product.new` , but I still don't understand what you are trying to do.  your buy action looks like  a standard create,.  Normally the page the has the form isn't the action it posts/puts to.   So in your case you could have the form as part of the index action,  set @products to Product.all, and @product to Product.new in that controller and put the form in index.html.erb

Comment: sorry,I can't understand your mean completely.You mean to add @products = Product.all in my action "buy"?Uh...I'm trying to put default "new" "create" "index" in the same view.I can see the list after I enter....Now if I add @products = Product.all in the "buy" and in the buy.html.erb simple_form_for Product.new. It will undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass.......thanks u very much~

Comment: So you want to have 1 "view" shows you all the products, and allows you to create new ones, with out having to go to to the new page, and then submit the form.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Or do you want to create a bunch of records via javacript and then add them all at once?   If so the model_name is would be product so that it can be referenced from the params hash as params[:product].  the [] just makes it an array.

Comment: Well,I think the first one is what I want.But actually I have another model named "order",I will pass all the product to the order.I'm not sure is this your second way?

Comment: So the first way can't pass value to another model?

Comment: you can pass whatever values you want back, the params hash is just a collection of the form values, Rails using the naming convention to separate/parse.

Comment: So what's your advice for me?It's first way better or second?

Comment: as I am still not 100% sure what your end goal, I not sure.  are you trying to build something like a shopping cart, where you add each product into the order, and then  place an order?  Or do you want to add a bunch of products to a page, then save them in 1 go (Like the link you referenced). Or do you just want to have the products list and the add product form on the same view (the code in my answer should do this)

Comment: I think the second way is my end goal.After I enter a product,it will list in the same page and I will save all the product in 1 go.Because of this Now I have two model, one is order and one is product,and order has_many product.If I want to do that the model is right?

Comment: If you want to add them all to the page via javascript, then save them all in one go under the order, look into accepts_nested_attributes_for and http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised  which can show you how to add/remove the fields via javascript, and then save them all in one go. The normal way to do this would be via the order model.  in Order#new you would create a new order, and an empty product,  then use Javascript to add more products, etc..